# Nuxt Auth + Laravel Passport - local scheme vs passport provider

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js, laravel-passport, nuxt-auth

I am trying to wrap my head around oauth2 so I actually know what I am doing, however not everything is clear.

I know that in OAuth2 we have various flows available. Quite popular ones are (I think):

- Authorization Code Grant
- Implicit Grant
- Password Grant

In my SPA I used https://auth.nuxtjs.org/ for handling user authorization. On the backend, there is Laravel Passport. This auth module offers us built-in support for OAuth as well as for some extra abstraction layers on the top of it - like Laravel Passport. I understand that these providers are sort of extensions of schemes, pre-configured for particular services.

I am not sure what is the difference between local scheme (https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local) which looks like that:

```
local: {
        token: {
          property: 'access_token',
          type: 'Bearer'
        },
        user: {
          property: 'user',
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {url: '/login', method: 'post'},
          logout: {url: '/logout', method: 'post'},
          user: {url: '/user', method: 'get'}
        }
      }
```

And Laravel Passport provider (https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/laravel-passport) which works like that (this one I can't get to work):

```
'laravelPassport': {
        provider: 'laravel/passport',
        endpoints: {
          userInfo:  {url: '/user', method: 'get'}
        },
        url: 'http://publisher-local.co.uk:8080/api/v1',
        clientId: '*',
        clientSecret: '****'
      }
```

Are they not the same thing? I mean Passport is just an Oauth thing and I am sending credentials there so I assume it is a **Password Grant Flow** in my first example?

If in passport provider which is based on Oauth scheme I would have `grantType:client_credentials` would it be considered a **Password Grant Flow** as well?

It gets even more confusing because when I try to use Passport Provider the redirects work a bit differently.

I am not sure what to choose and how to understand the whole process.